# Visible panels CSS on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have a javascript based web, where one grid and one map are in the same position.
With different button 'TABLA / MAPA' I change css properties.

```
 .back{
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;

}
.front{
    visibility:hidden;
    display:none;
}
```

With this css by default as you can see I get the two layers overlaped.
I tried z-index too but I don't get nothing.

https://app.prodevelop.es/gisport/cas/client-gisport/latest/

Comment: What version(s) of IE?

Comment: At least on 9+ versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using using css styles you can use jQuery .hide() and .show() methods.

I have done a jsFiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/zf9v4/1/

```
$('#div2').hide();
$('#div1').show();
```